ShaderMask on Text gradient issue
I want to apply a gradient to text. Below is the code that works fine until I specify height: 1.
For some reason, shader doesn't apply to the bottom part of text (see black notch at the bottom of "y" letter).
I thought the problem was that height parameter affects the bounds.
But if I specify much larger values in shaderCallback, it doesn't affect the result.
Any ideas how to apply gradient to text even with any height values?
no height specified

height: 1

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: Body()),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      fontSize: 48,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 1,
    );
    return Center(
      child: ShaderMask(
        blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
        shaderCallback: (bounds) => _gradient.createShader(bounds),
        child: const Text('Why?', style: style),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const _gradient = LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.red]);


You can use strutStyle instead the style only for the height.
const Text(
          'Why?',
          style: style,
          strutStyle: StrutStyle(
            height: 1,
          ),
        ),

More info about strutStyle: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/StrutStyle-class.html
